# Having a small issue with javascript/css analog clock

Tags: javascript, css, clock

My clock doesn't seem to run when the page loads, unless I end the web address with the ID of the clock which is `#clock`.

This doesn't run on load:
http://maxim.comze.com/clock/index.html

This runs on load:
http://maxim.comze.com/clock/index.html#clock

I tried `$(document).ready(function()` but it doesn't seem to make it run on load.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you show your full code when `#clock` you put with javascript function

Comment: `$(function(){` is the same as `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: This is the code: http://maxim.comze.com/clock/js/experiment.js

Comment: More information on the original experiment can be found at [Paul Hayes blog](http://www.paulrhayes.com/2009-03/an-analogue-clock-using-only-css/).

Answer (score 1):

The issue was you were calling the script on load once. So it was working, only once. You needed `setInterval();` to run it every second. Updated your code, also moved some stuff around. Have a look: **http://jsfiddle.net/uMVnE/4/**

```
setInterval(function(){
        startClock(prop)
},100);
```

**EDIT** Just realised it is not as smooth as your original. Is that an issue?

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually it's better now, I think it takes less CPU that it updates every second instead of constantly updating the second handle.

Comment: No problem. I just realised there was a problem with the `hour` variable. It was not returning the right value on my jsfiddle. It's fixed now.

Comment: Doing 'setInterval' alone may lead to the time becoming less accurate the longer it runs, I would recommend periodically checking your time against the actual time. You'll just need a Date object you can call '.getTime()' with.

Comment: The way it's set up at the moment, on each call from setInterval it is getting a new date(h:m:s) and converting that into degrees then rotating the hands. I've put it side by side with [an official clock](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=136) and it was perfect to the second, over 3-4 minutes.

Comment: It sounds like it's covered then :)

Comment: Was worth the double check though (: